Symfony new Logger changes throws exception, deprecated, use HttpKernel's DebugLoggerConfigurator instead
I am using symfony 5 and monolog v3.7
Since yesterday we faced a new exception:
    #message: "User Deprecated: Since symfony/monolog-bridge 6.4: The "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger" class is deprecated, use HttpKernel's DebugLoggerConfigurator instead."


In our application, we don't directly utilize this class. Instead, we consistently inject LoggerInterface and take advantage of its functionalities

I upgraded from Symfony 5.4 to 6.4 today following the official guide without fixing the aforementioned monolog deprecations beforehand.
There were no problems with monolog-bridge or similar after the upgrade and the deprecation messages did not show up with 6.4 either. So I would say that you can ignore those messages in this particular case.
